# Export to CSV without writing to file system

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have been using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` for exporting data from my Winforms application. I like it because I can export and display the data without writing to the file system. Unfortunately, the Excel instances do not clean up like I want.

I would like to create a CSV file instead. I can do this, however my requirements are to display the data immediately in whatever program handles CSV files on the user's computer, but not save the file unless the user decides to do so.

Is this possible, and if so how?

If not, I would appreciate any suggestions on how to handle this scenario.

Comment: It sounds like what you need is rows and cells in Excel. It existing as a CSV (on disk or not) as a middle step seems inconsequential. Just put the values in the Spreadsheet through interop.

Comment: The Excel instances do not clean up when the user closes the application. I also do not want to have to ensure that Excel is installed on each workstation that uses the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to "Serialize" my class if I have any or Create my CSV "Manually" to avoid using Excel maybe using something like:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566656/CSV-Serializer-for-NET

I would save this it into a MemoryStream and when the user decides to save to this save I would move the MermoryStream into a file something like:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("somename.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
    myMemoryStream.WriteTo(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the "whatever program" is the problem. A specific program would give you (or not) an API, like Excel does.

Saving the file, you could use" System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathOfTheCsv)", and the OS would do the magic (with the proper permissions). But you don't want to save the file...

Can you use google docs? You could use the available API.